# Is there a word that means "having beautiful hair"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know that "callipygian" means "having beautiful buttocks"... so I was wondering if there is an English word that means "having beautiful hair".

I tried googling this but couldn't find anything so far.

Comment: I thought ***trichogenic*** might do it (by analogy with ***photogenic***), but apparently that word (which isn't in OED anyway) is often used in the context of tumours that start in hair follicles. Probably not the kind of association you're looking for.

Comment: @Fumble Not at all. Trichogenic is for hair oil, nor hair :)

Comment: You could coin *rechairché*.  (I want to write *rec* ***hair*** *ché*, but can't get around the typography constraints.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only single word that can be used is ***beautiful-haired*** as a compound adjective. Though, it is not that common and should be used with a noun after (as in *beautiful-haired* girl).

> All the most beautiful-haired celebrities have been surprisingly upfront lately about how rarely they wash their hair.
>
> <sup>http://www.thegloss.com/2014/05/23/beauty/why-washing-face-hair-is-bad/</sup>

On the other hand, there is a word, *callithrix*, that its original meaning is "having beautiful hair" or "beautiful-haired" but it is used in zoology today to define a genus of New World monkeys of the family Callitrichidae, the family containing marmosets and tamarins. These primates have beautiful hair.

The name *Callithrix* is derived from the Greek words kallos, meaning beautiful, and thrix, meaning hair.

> late 18th century: from modern Latin Callitrichidae (plural), from Greek kallitrikhos 'having beautiful hair'.
>
> <sup>http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/callitrichid</sup>

Comment: What girl would want to be called such names! Lol.

Comment: I actually spotted ***callitriche*** trawling through the relevant section in OED earlier, but I must have missed ***Greek καλλίτριχος beautiful-haired*** in the etymology. I discarded it on the basis of the definition - *a genus of small water-weeds inhabiting ponds and ditches; also called **Water Star-wort**.* FWIW, *callitrichid* isn't actually *in* the "real" OED.

Comment: Of course if it is the work of a hairdresser one could say ***beautifully coiffured***.